# Sampling by columns in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Given a Hive table as following:

```
> desc T;
dim1 string
dim2 string
dim3 string
value1 int
value2 int
```

I am trying randomly sample 1,000 rows by groups `(dim1, dim2, dim3)`.

An approach to this is:

```
# bash
for dim1 in dim1_1, dim1_2; do
     for dim2 in dim2_1, dim2_2; do
        for dim3 in dim3_1, dim3_2; do
            hive -e "select * from T where dim1=$dim1 and dim2=$dim2 and dim3=$dim3 limit 1000;"
done done done
```

Then 2^3=8 queries will be executed successively. Is there any more efficient way?

Comment: `limit` is definitly not a  random sample

Answer (score 1):

```
with    dim as
        (
            select  struct(d1.v,d2.v,d3.v) as vals

            from    (select 1) x
                    lateral view explode (array(1,2)) d1 as v -- dim1_1 = 1 dim1_2 = 2
                    lateral view explode (array(3,4)) d2 as v -- dim2_1 = 3 dim2_2 = 4
                    lateral view explode (array(5,6)) d3 as v -- dim3_1 = 5 dim3_2 = 6
        )

select  *

from   (select  row_number () over
                (
                    partition by    dim1,dim2,dim3
                    order by        rand()
                ) as rn
               ,*

        from    t

        where   struct(t.dim1,t.dim2,t.dim3) in (select vals from dim)
        ) t

where   rn <= 1000
;
```

Comment: Fixed a typo, the order by should be by `rand()`

Comment: Are you still here?